# Linear Equations Consistency

Tags: linear-algebra

Given a system of linear equations: 
$$
\left\{\begin{array}{rcrcrcl}
\displaystyle{3x} & \displaystyle{+} & \displaystyle{2y} & \displaystyle{+}
& \displaystyle{z} & \displaystyle{=} & \displaystyle{10}
\\
\displaystyle{2x} & \displaystyle{+} & \displaystyle{y} & \displaystyle{+}
& \displaystyle{5z} & \displaystyle{=} & \displaystyle{19}
\\
\displaystyle{x} & \displaystyle{+} & \displaystyle{y} & \displaystyle{-}
& \displaystyle{4z} & \displaystyle{=} & \displaystyle{15}
\end{array}\right.
$$
does the system consistent ?. How do I know it is consistent or not using either elimination or substitution method ?.

Comment: But I was asked to prove it using elimination or substitution

Comment: Set it up as an augmented matrix and put in $RREF$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Proceed to attempt to solve the system by elimination or substitution.

Eventually, assuming you make no mistakes, you will arrive at one of three possibilities:

1. One of the unknowns is left equal to a number;  this system of equations is soluble and unique values all the variables can eventually be determined; in effect, the three equations represent three planes that intersect at one point
2. All of the variables magically are eliminated and you are left with an equation that says a number is equal to itself;  this system of equations is consistent and has an infinite number of possible solutions.  In this case the three equations represent three planes that intersect in a line;
3. All the variables magically disappear and you are left with some number equals some other number; this system of equations is inconsistent and has no solution

EDIT:  In the **particular example** given, **by coincidence**, it turns out if you subtract Equation #2 from Equation #1, you get:$$x+y-4z=-9$$which, if you subtract Equation #3 produces:$$0=-24$$so the system given is inconsistent...

More generally, if you decide to eliminate **any** variable by taking the equations in  pairs, multiplying by appropriate coefficients and subtracting, the eventual result will be one of the three above...

Comment: So if I subtract each equations and produce wrong statement like 0 = -24 then it is inconsistent? Then there's no need to use any solving method if I just need to subtract each of the equations...?

Comment: No:  see edit...

Answer (score 0):

Add second and third to get $3x+2y+z=34$. Comparing it with the first equation, you get $10=9$. Hence inconsistent.